# Python 3: How to convert unicode text in original form?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode

I am getting text in form `Al\\\\u0027sPlace` which actually is `Al's Place`.
Same is for `‘â\x80\x94`

How do I get `Al's Place` in original form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it encoded with [`unicode-escape` encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) twice; reverse it.

```
>>> text = 'Al\\\\u0027sPlace'
>>> text.encode().decode('unicode-escape').encode().decode('unicode-escape')
"Al'sPlace"
```

Comment: It worked but how it encoded twice? I did not do any such thing at all. All I did that called appending object in a list.

Comment: @Volatil3. I guessed. Without the code that generated the text `Al\\\\u0027sPlace`, I cannot know.

Comment: OK - and what about `â\x80\x94`?

Comment: @Volatil3, `â\x80\x94`, Could you let me know where this string come from?

Comment: I am scraping data from a website.

Comment: It would be nice to see your code that fetch the site and the url so that I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143350/discussion-between-volatil3-and-falsetru).